# How to restart the whole app on pause?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

how can i close all activities and restart the app from the beginning when it goes on pause ?
for example when i press the home button it goes to on pause mode and when i launch it again it starts from the last activity i want to close all activities on onPause method so how can i do that ?

MainActivity / SettingActivity / SampleActivity

i want to close all of them and again restart the app from the MainActivity 
and i want to start from onCreate method not just go to the MainActivity

Comment: Why do you think that this is a good idea? Bear in mind that your activity is paused while it is still visible, such as when a system dialog appears over top of it, or when the user is using split-screen mode on Android 7.0+ devices.

Comment: Because for some reason it stops working and i can't find out why
there is just some images that i load with Glide and thats it.
on some devices it works perfectly but on some it breaks.
i simply download image links and load them with Glide and nothing more...

Answer (score 0):

In onPause() method call the activity that you want to show

```
  @Override
public void onPause() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set [noHistory](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) attribute to be true.

> Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack
>   and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away
>   from it and it's no longer visible on screen — **"true" if it should be
>   finished**, and "false" if not. The default value is "false".
>
> A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical
>   trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the
>   user **will not be able to return to it**. In this case,
>   onActivityResult() is never called if you start another activity for a
>   result from this activity.